# How to parse DE 48—Additional Data—Private Use in mastercard?

Tags: java, jpos

Could you please help me to parse the DE48 value from the below ISO
    Message. I am using Jpos - jar in java for getting the ISOMessage.

```
In XML we used the IFE_LLLCHAR value, for that we are
getting value:"R9203421" <<LLL><sub-element id><length><value>> eg: 
<<R><92><03><421>>.
```

We are having below queries

1. Is it Mastercard.xml isofield tag is correct or not?
2. How to parse the DE-48 value?
3. TLVList method is giving error, so any other way is there to get the DE-48 value?
4. Tag DE-55 is giving Junk value if we using IFE_LLLCHAR class.

Answer (score 0):

`org.jpos.iso.packager.EuroSubFieldPackager` is your friend.

You need to configure something like this:

```
<isofieldpackager
  id="48"
  length="999"
  name="Additional Data"
  class="org.jpos.iso.IFE_LLLBINARY"
      packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.EuroSubFieldPackager">
  <isofield
      id="0"
      length="1"
      name="PLACEHOLDER"
      class="org.jpos.iso.IFE_CHAR"/>
   <isofield 
            id="0001" 
            length="21" 
            name="Account Number" 
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFEMC_LLLCHAR"/>
    <isofield 
            id="0002" 
            length="3" 
            name="Product Identifier" 
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFEMC_LLLCHAR"/>
     ...
     ...
```

In field 55, you probably want to use `org.jpos.iso.IFE_LLLBINARY`.

Answer (score 0):

We dont know the subelement id's, so how to configure XML? We are getting child element value                                         TCC subelement length data
eg:"R9203421" <> <   <92>     <03>   <421>>

it may be change like "R9203421120151701715101234567892", Based upon the dynamic string i have to form the jpos message.

Comment: Hi, Did you get any lead in this. I am having the same problem. Can you share the MasterCard packager for DE 48 if it worked for you?